# 'The amount of qubit(4)/clbit(0) arguments does not match the gate expectation (2).'

Tags: qiskit

Trying to apply a four-qubit unitary gate, getting an error message I don't understand (see title).

Here is my code

`````
import numpy as np
from qiskit import QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister, QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.extensions import UnitaryGate
gate16x16=np.load('m0.npy', allow_pickle=True) #shape [4,4]
q = QuantumRegister(4)
c = ClassicalRegister(4)
qc = QuantumCircuit(q)

qc.unitary(gate16x16,q)
qc.measure(q[0], c[0])
````
`````

Comment: If the gate that you have loaded into the variable `gate16x16` is indeed of dimensions $4 \times 4$ as implied in the comment `#shape [4,4]`, then this is the problem. $4 \times 4$ unitary matrices are representation of quantum gates for $2$ qubits, not for $4$ qubits. For $4$ qubits a unitary operator of dimensions $16 \times 16$ is needed.

Comment: Could you please provide the matrix you load?